# Strange product list look : which Magento module?

Tags: category, module, extensions, design

Does someone know which Magento module allow to do product list look like this : https://www.gemmyo.com/pour-elle/les-essentiels/bagues.html ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a module, it's more of a theming - you can edit list.phtml to get the list to look like that

Comment: Thx for your answer, I think it's more than editing list.phtml from an administration point of view. There is also image with link inside the list. I doubt it is a bloc static nomenclature like "img_cat_ID_row_2". Also all the list doesn't look exactly the same, for example https://www.gemmyo.com/pour-elle/les-essentiels/bracelets.html. Maybe it is a custom module developped by this brand, or an existing one ? Maybe Magento 2 ... ?